# Apache CXF endpoint request gives SocketException :connection read timeout when the soap envelop length is large(>5kb)

Tags: soap, apache-camel, cxf, apache-servicemix

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)[:1.8.0_51]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)[:1.8.0_51]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)[:1.8.0_51]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)[:1.8.0_51]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)[:1.8.0_51]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)[:1.8.0_51]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)[:1.8.0_51]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1535)[:1.8.0_51]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)[:1.8.0_51]
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)[:1.8.0_51]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.getResponseCode(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:332)[180:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.4]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.do
```

Tried configuring the http conduit, still getting the same exception ..

```
<http-conf:conduit name="{http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http}SoapPort.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:client Connection="Keep-Alive"
               Connectiontimeout = 0 receivetimout =0 
                      MaxRetransmits="1"
                      AllowChunking="false" />
  </http-conf:conduit>
```

Tried increasing the receive timeout and connect timeout in http-conf: conduit

```
 <http-conf:client Connection="Keep-Alive"
               Connectiontimeout = 60000 receivetimout =60000 
                      MaxRetransmits="1"
                      AllowChunking="false" />
  </http-conf:conduit>
```

But still not working but getting socketexception : connection reset

And can anyone help by explaining the difference between  'read tim out' and 'connection reset' error msg of socketexception ?

And it works absolutely fine when the same request is posted through soap client application(boomerang)

I am stuck up with this thing fr a long while . Please anyone help resolving this issue.